# MongoDB javascript string equality condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, javascript-objects

I have a mongodb query or script that will update all employee team project and will change the team project to "DUMMY" only when the current project is "bbb234". I got a weird behavior  since there are some project (bbb234) which are not changed to "DUMMY". I am not sure if my condition is wrong but only the first 10 or 12 records are changed. Only late records are not changed even when the team project is "bbb234".

To understand what I meant, please see the script below.

```
db.getCollection('employees').find(
    { "teams.project" : {
            $in: [ "aaa123", "bbb234" ]
      }
    }
).forEach(e => {
    // skip when there are no teams
    if (!e.teams) {
        return;
    }

    e.teams.forEach(team => {

         if (team.project === "bbb234") {
             team.project = 'DUMMY';
         }

        // This is OK, it will display 'DUMMY' for all team with previous project value of `bbb234`
        // print(team.project); 

        // When displaying team, the condition is `team.project === "bbb234"` is not always true
        // The first 10 employee records have updated team project, 
        // while after that...  the other records still show team.project = "bbb234"
        // print(team);
    });

    // Update employee with the corrected/updated team project
    db.getCollection('employees').updateOne({"_id": e._id}, {$set: {"teams": e.teams}});
})
```

When I check the records, `teams.project` value is String. I am not sure where in my script is wrong or not able to handle the condition correctly. I know this is pretty easy but I cannot figure out where I did wrong and why only the early records are updated/changed.

**Update:**

I tried `.toArray()` but still I am getting the same error/issue.
I really find this wierd

```
var _employees = db.getCollection('employees').find(
    { "teams.project" : {
            $in: [ "aaa123", "bbb234" ]
      }
    }
).toArray();

_employees .forEach(e => {
    // skip when there are no teams
    if (!e.teams) {
        return;
    }

    e.teams.forEach(team => {

         if (team.project === "bbb234") {
             team.project = 'DUMMY';
         }

        // Still, this is OK
        // print(team.project); 

        // Same issue as with the previous query/script
        // print(team);
    });

    // Update employee with the corrected/updated team project
    db.getCollection('employees').updateOne({"_id": e._id}, {$set: {"teams": e.teams}});
})
```

Comment: Your comments suggest printing `team.project` shows _DUMMY_ for all, and on the very next line printing `team` shows _DUMMY_ only for some?

Comment: I deleted my incorrect answer. Still, I recommend checking for any (white)space or anything else that could explain why some of your strings are not equal to "bbb234". Did you try checking if team.project.trim()=="bbb234" does work?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated that comment. It will show `DUMMY` for those team with previous project value of `bbb234`... not really all. When I just `print(team.project)` the condition works perfectly since the print values are correct. Problem is when I `print(team)` only the early teams have the updated project value (`DUMMY`). Other team still displays `bbb234` (old value). I really find this weird since `employees.team.project` is a `String` field.

Comment: mongodb objects are read only objects...u cant modify them

Comment: You can use .toArray() to convert on raw object.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that... but what is weird is that around first 10 teams when printed shown the updated project `DUMMY`... but after that project `bbb234` was not updated

Comment: @xdeepakv I added `.toArray()` but still I am getting the same error/issue. Maybe I misunderstood or misused it.

Comment: Damn, everything works...  I mean, my initial script works, @xdeepakv suggestion also works. The problem was with my IDE (robo 3T 1.4.4). I observed when I tried another solution where in I will clone the object, etc. There are some weird errors that comes out. So I tried my older version of robo 3T (1.3) and everything works like magic. That is why the error is so weird, the culprit is my IDE. It wasted hours of trials, and searches. Upgrading to the latest version seems not advisable base from this experience. Thanks everyone!